# What will be the major impacts if I removed all core css from Magento core and changing core class names?

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.4

Im using magento 2.4. I would like to know the impacts of removing all magento core css and changing some of core class names.

As per my understanding below areas will be impact

- Magento Upgrade
- Security patches
- JS (many js depends on core magento class)
- 3rd party extension and JS

Please share your thoughts and share some official links if you have.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what's the aim ?

Comment: I have created new framework all the css and some of common JS load from the the new framework

Comment: I am still not sure to understand. You want a headless magento or you want to create a new framework ? Answer depends on the aim.